# JavaScript não funciona no WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Estou executando o seguinte código JavaScript no site que fiz em WordPress.

```
var itens = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

console.log(itens);
```

Estou puxando de um arquivo que esta na pasta js, mas ele não trás os itens do h1, porém se eu executar esse mesmo código acima no console do navegador ele funciona.
Alguém sabe me falar o que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Não sei se ajuda, mas este é o print do Console do navegador => https://prnt.sc/les18p2

Comment: Acredito que o problema esteja na importação do arquivo. Certifique-se que o arquivo está sendo carregado. Atualiza o arquivo adicionando um alert('teste') e vê se tem algum resultado

Comment: Tenta colocando o código dentro deste evento: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ CÓDIGO AQUI });`... pode ser que esteja executando o código antes de carregar o DOM.

Comment: Obrigado @Sam deu certo com a solução que tu falou, tu sabe me falar o porque deste problema? será que é uma peculiaridade do WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu Wordpress está carregando o script antes do carregamento completo do DOM (provavelmente no `head` da página). Com isso o código não encontra os elementos porque eles ainda não foram carregados (o `head` vem antes do `body` onde estão os elementos visuais da página).

Para resolver, adicione o código no evento `DOMContentLoaded`, porque aí o script só será executado quando o DOM for totalmente carregado:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var itens = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
   console.log(itens);
});
```

Comment: Valeu meu chapa o/